# How to build a bootstrap dropdown with incrementor field

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a dropdown that functions like in the image below:

[image: Dropdown with incrementing/decrementing fields]

I need a dropdown field within the dropdown field, and then I need a couple of fields that allow incrementing/decrementing.

I couldn't even get a dropdown within the dropdown to work right. I tried variations of the following:

I've tried variations of:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <form>
    <div class="dropdown form-group clearfix">
                  <button class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Fare Class
                  <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                      <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Economy</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Business</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">First</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I didn't even know where to begin for the increment parts of each text field.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I added a variation of the code which I tried. I didn't even know where to start for the incrementing numbers part.